# Change language programatically in Android with country

Tags: android, localization, locale

I try to change my locale in an android application.
If I use only language all is ok, but today I added portuguese-br translation to my app.

Code:

```
Locale locale;
        if(language.contains("-"))  // In this case, the locale specify also the country
        {
            String[] country_locale = language.split("-");
            locale = new Locale(country_locale[0], country_locale[1]); 
        }
        else
            locale = new Locale(language); 
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

All is ok untill last line.
I know because in a previous piece of my program i could get some string with the correct pt-br locale with this code:

```
Resources resources = new Resources(ctx.getAssets(), ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(), new_config);
```

updateConfiguration set my locale to English if Locale was defined with a country code.

String.xml is in values-pt-rBR

While debugging Locale value is set to pt-BR.

EDIT: After further tests, this works on my Android phone, but doesn't work on my tablet (both Sambung with android 4.4.2).
What could be the reason?

EDIT 2: Also over the emulator work if I use a phone, not work if I use a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

On your current Activity, try call the follow after your code:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

This will recreate your Activity and, then, reload the string resources.